# Disabling ASLR under Debian, Read-Only Error

Tags: linux, memory, debian

I am doing a debugging project for a computer security course, but find that the memory addresses for certain variables I am trying to examine changes between runs. I spoke with the instructor, and he suggested disabling ASLR for my session to keep the memory addresses static for the analysis process.

I am running a Debian instance hosted in Cloud9.

To accomplish this, I use the command:

`echo 0 | tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`

I run this command under root. When I do this, the OS spits back the error:

`tee: /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space: Read-only file system`

I understand to be perfectly normal behavior but non-ideal for what I'm trying to do.

How do I go about disabling the read-only flag on the system? I understand that `mount` may provide a solution, so the following is a dump of the output of `mount` on my VM.

```
none on / type aufs (rw,relatime,si=18e455316acd065c,dio,dirperm1)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=666)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/mapper/volg1-lvdata on /mnt type ext4 (ro,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/volg1-lvdata on /nix type ext4 (ro,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/volg1-lvdata on /mnt/shared type ext4 (ro,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/volg1-lvdata on /etc/resolv.conf type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/volg1-lvdata on /etc/hostname type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/volg1-lvdata on /etc/hosts type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=65536k)
/dev/mapper/volg1-lvdata on /root/.ssh/authorized_keys type ext4 (ro,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/volg1-lvdata on /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys type ext4 (ro,relatime,data=ordered)
devpts on /dev/console type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
proc on /proc/asound type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/bus type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/fs type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/irq type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/sys type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/sysrq-trigger type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /proc/kcore type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=755)
tmpfs on /proc/timer_list type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=755)
tmpfs on /proc/timer_stats type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=755)
tmpfs on /proc/sched_debug type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/firmware type tmpfs (ro,relatime)
```

Comment: You can't change this on virtual machine. Try on your own computer.

Comment: You can disable ASLR on a virtual machine. I just accomplished that very thing in a VMWare Debian instance. Do you mean you can't change the mount to read-only?

Comment: Sorry, i was not too accurate. ( s/virtual machine/guest os/ ) VMware emulates the all hardware, so you can do anything as bare metal. Cloud9 uses xen or other paravirtualization to create mostly individual systems. But the memory management is the same and the host os do the job. It gives much more performance than emulating the fully x86 hardware.